# How to set left and right border gradient precisely in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a `Border` and I am trying to set its `BorderBrush` to have left border gradient from `#D3D3D3` to `BFBFBF` and right border gradient from `#BFBFBF` to `#717171`. The problem is that if I do this:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#D3D3D3"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#BFBFBF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="#BFBFBF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#717171"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I need to choose `Offset` properly, which is hard. Furthermore I need different offsets for different border sizes. Generally if I have `BorderThickness = 10, 0, 10, 0` I want border gradient to be C1-C2 colors in 0-10 pixels in the left part and C2-C3 colors in 0-10 pixels in the right part (or `border.Width` - `border.Width + 10` pixels). I do not care about Top-Bottom borders and I am fine having them as solid color.

Is there anyway I could achieve what I've described?

I want border to look something like this (this picture is bottom crop of the panel I am trying to do):

[image]

I've you have any other suggestions - please share

Comment: You could probably just add a "conductor" to the control which watches the control for changes (you can probably use an attached behavior/properties for this). It can check the border thickness property and create a gradient with the correct dimensions when the thickness changes. You could provide this component with a base colour which it would use to generate the gradients

Comment: @Charleh I could do that, but it sounds so hacky... These panels I am trying to imitate are all around in old QT programs and late Win 98 design, and I cannot believe WPF can't do that in a simpler way. Anyway, thanks for the tip - if I won't find a better solution, I will have to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you cannot have different gradients on different sides of the border elements.

You should instead use two nested `Border` elements, one with left side only and second with the right side of the border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <!-- Left side gradient -->
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,0">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <!-- Right side gradient -->
        </Border.BorderBrush>

        <!-- Content here -->
    </Border>
</Border>
```

These way you can use simple gradients on the sides.

Writing up these gradients should be easy with `MappingMode.Absolute`.

**EDIT**

It seems that setting the right border gradient with `MappingMode.Absolute` is not possible.

Much easier solution would be to have simple `StackPanel`/`Grid` control with gradient-filled `Rectangle`s as border parts:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Rectangle Width="10">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
              <!-- Left side gradient -->
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <!-- Content here -->

    <Rectangle Width="10">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
              <!-- Right side gradient -->
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I feel like your answer should bring me to the result I am looking for, but I'm still missing a bit. I can do absolute positioning with the left border via `MappingMode=Absolute` , but how do I do the right one? I want the right gradient to start from element width to (width + border width)

Comment: @Archeg It seems that setting right border is not so easy after all. See my edit.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer, but due to the complexity of the solution I would avoid using it (so I won't spoil my xaml as I have many such panels), unless I am asked to strictly follow the design as the customer is yet not sure whether I am allowed to deviate. Thank you.

Comment: @Archeg You could always wrap it as a `ControlTemplate` for `ContentControl`.